# Adding custom handlers with AppleScript to command bar controls in MS powerpoint 2011

Tags: applescript

I have built a command bar using applescript like this.
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"

```
make new command bar with properties {bar type:menubar command bar, bar position:bar floating, name:"Ani Tech", built in:true, entry_index:1, row index:0, embedded:false, embeddable:false, top:300, protection:no protection, width:1000, height:500, id:1}
make new command bar control in command bar "Ani Tech" with properties {control type:control button, entry_index:0, begin group:true, button style:button caption, name:"Create MCQ", face id:1}
set btnAbout to make new command bar control in command bar "Turning Tech" with properties {control type:control button, entry_index:1, begin group:false, button style:button caption, name:"Save MCQ", face id:2}
make new command bar control in command bar "Ani Tech" with properties {control type:button icon, entry_index:2, begin group:false, button style:button icon, name:"Tool", face id:0}
**set onaction of btnAbout to "sayHello()"**
```

end tell

on sayHello()
    display dialog "Hello"
end sayHello

I am not able to call subroutine "sayHello" on clicking of this control. I have added action but it is not called there. If anyone has solution to this problem as how to add or call any subroutine on clicking of command bar control.
-Anirudh

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "`my`" prefix to call your script's handlers from within a `tell` block.

```
my sayHello()
```

(see [relevant passage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW3) of the AppleScript Language Guide)

Comment: I could not test it, however, because on my Mac your AppleScript crashes with an error when attempting to create new command bars...